# Laravel queue listeners on multiple machines on the same queue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

I currently have a multi-server Laravel setup. I have multiple servers that are load balanced and share a database.

Each instance is also running a queue listener. I want to be able to dispatch two types of jobs:

1. A job that is only run once (e.g send email, update a model, etc)
2. A job that is run on ALL queue listeners (e.g delete a file from the filesystem)

The first I think is quite simple to implement, but unsure how to go about implementing the second one. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use supervisor for queues? Do you use database driver for queues?

Comment: Using supervisor and database driver. Open to using Redis or something like SQS

Comment: You will need to not use queues for this, or make special queues (names) for each machine you use (problems with provisioning servers the more servers you have the more tedious it gets...). You will most likely end up with one master machine that will have to propagate "signals" to other machines to do the jobs; you can leverage shared database. If server count is small I would go with named queues.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a queue listener or worker handle specific queues. For example run a queue listener or worker to handle `emails` queue.

```
php artisan queue:listen --queue=emails
php artisan queue:work --queue=emails
```

You can now dispatch jobs to a this queue

```
dispatch((new Job)->onQueue('emails'));
```

This can help you setup multiple listeners/workers to handle different queues based on your requirements.

Comment: But how would I go about getting a Job to run for ALL listeners on a queue?

Comment: As I understand this is not the problem; problem is to propagate signal to "delete" files to all servers.

Comment: @nothingtosee the job gets popped from the queue to be processed by a listener or worker, therefore having a single job run on all listeners would be hard without considerable changes to the queue mechanism. One solution would be to name all your queues uniquely and have an array of queue names and dispatch your job to all the queues in the array.